# PHP, resource id# instead of actual string

Tags: php, mysql

I have run across a problem during my query service to add a row in an online database in PHP. The addition of the row works just fine. I get user id and book id from the url and fetch the names of the book and the user to put into the row which i add to my third and last table. 
When I get the names, put them in an array, json encode it and then echo it, it works. But when I put them in the row it prints resource id#3 and resource id#4 instead of the names.
Any ideas?

Here is my service:

```
<?php

$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","root");

$userid=$_GET['uid'];
$id = $_GET['bookid'];
$type = $_GET['type'];
$zero = '0';
$one = '1';
$date = date("Y-m-d");

$arr = array();

if (!$con)
{
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    echo "error connection";
}

mysql_select_db("Jineel_lib",$con) or die("Could not select database");

$bkName = mysql_query("SELECT Name from books where ID='".$id."'");

$userName = mysql_query("SELECT Name from people WHERE User_ID='".$userid."'");


while($obj = mysql_fetch_object($userName))
{
    $arr[] = $obj;        
}

echo json_encode($arr);

if($type == 'borrow')
{
   $query="UPDATE books set Availablity = '".$zero."' where ID= '".$id."' ";
    mysql_query($query) or die (" borrow operation failed due to query 1");

   $query1="INSERT into borrowed (BookID, BookName, BorrowerID, BorrowedName, DateBorrowed, Extended, Returned) values('".$id."','".$bkName."','".$userid."','".$userName."','".$date."','".$zer‌​o."','".$zero."')";
    mysql_query($query1) or die (" borrow operation failed to due query 2");

    echo "borrow success";

}

else if($type=='return')

{
    $query="UPDATE books set Availablity = '".$one."' where ID= '".$id."' ";
    mysql_query($query) or die (" return operation failed");

    $query1="UPDATE borrowed set Returned = '".$one."' where BookID= '".$id."' ";
    mysql_query($query1) or die (" return operation failed 1");

    echo "return success";
}

else

echo "invalid parameters";

?>
```

THANK YOU IN ADVANCE

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: What error happens where exactly?

Comment: Your code is vulnerable for SQL injections as you pass values from user input directly into your query. See: [Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com).

Answer (score 0):

You don't actually retrieve the userName value here:

```
$userName = mysql_query("SELECT Name...
```

`$userName` is just the result resource object returned from the query.  You do use `mysql_fetch_object` later on, which is appropriate, but then you try to use the actual result resource in your insert query:

```
$query1="INSERT into borrowed ...
```

It gets converted to the string you see.  Instead, you need to use `$obj->Name` (you fetch the result into `$obj`, and presumably there is only one result).  If there is more than one possible result, you will have to do that in a loop.

---

Listen to all of the comments on your question.